# XML display element values

Tags: c#, xml

Currently working with an XML which looks like this. `filename` introduced below is a `List<string>`

```
<Path> 
    <Entry>
        <File>name</File>
        <File>folder</File>
        <File>directory</File>
        <File>drive</File>
        <File>filename</File>
    </Entry>
</Path>
```

Trying to get my code to display values of `File` element

C# code I have tried:

```
  XDocument filefolder = null;
  filefolder = XDocument.Load;
  string xmlfile = "Path/Entry/File";
    foreach(var item in filefolder.GetXPathElements(xmlfile))
   {
     if(item.Name.ToString() == "File")
      {
        filename = item.Descendants("Entry").Elements("File").Select(val => val.Value).ToList();
      }
   }
```

My code runs well inside the if statement, but I don't get any values for `File`. I get the `count = 0` for `File` values.

How can I get my code to display all the values of `File`?

Comment: What is `xdoc` and `xpath`?

Comment: @gunr2171 that is what I used to load my XML file. The thing is what can/should I change in the if statement?

Comment: Don't use value which will give error when null : filename = filefolder.Descendants("Entry").Elements("File").Select(val => (string)val).ToList(),  You are also missing the file name : filefolder = XDocument.Load("filename");

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model from XML using the link https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

Then you can deserialize the XML into the model as follows. Once XML is deserialized then LINQ can be used to query.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Entry")]
public class Entry {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="File")]
    public List<string> File { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Path")]
public class ModelPath {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Entry")]
    public Entry Entry { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize the xml as:

```
string inputXmlFilePath = @"D:\Docs\Test\myfile.xml";
ModelPath modelPathObject = null;
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ModelPath));
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(MappingFilePath, FileMode.Open))
{
 modelPathObject = (ModelPath)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
}

Console.WriteLine("Total file lines count:" + modelPathObject.Entry.File.Count);
foreach (var item in modelPathObject.Entry.File)
{
 Console.WriteLine("File value is:" + item.ToString());
}
```